# How do I write an image to Dropbox directly?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, dropbox

I'm trying to reduce read/write on my sd card by writing image files to DropBox directly. I captured the image into stream, but I don't know how to write it to Dropbox. This is with the raspberry pi.

```
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox('token')
stream = io.BytesIO()

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.resolution = (1280,960)
    camera.capture(stream,format='jpeg')
stream.seek(0)
im = Image.open(stream)
dbx.files_upload(im,"/test.jpg",mute=True)
```

i get the following error, but not sure what it means or how to fix it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./camera.py", line 25, in <module>
    dbx.files_upload(im,"/test.jpg",mute=True)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dropbox/base.py", line 1225, in files_upload
f,

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dropbox/dropbox.py", line 249, in request
    timeout=timeout)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dropbox/dropbox.py", line 341, in request_json_string_with_retry
    timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dropbox/dropbox.py", line 385, in request_json_string
    type(request_binary))

TypeError: expected request_binary as binary type, got <type 'instance'>
```

Comment: you need to upload the image data to dropbox, not the image stream; try something like `files_upload(im.getdata(), ...)` or `files_upload(im.tobytes(), ...)`

Comment: thank you! Resolved this with files_upload(stream.getvalue(), ...)